# large-scale string comparison

Tags: python, string-comparison, large-data

I'm trying to find similar string pairs in a large string set. I have around 100 million strings, and string similarity is measured as edit distance. For example, "this is a sentence" and "this is also a sentence" are similar.

It is not practical to calculate the similarity between each two strings, resulting 100M x 100M calculations. I'm considering a divide-and-conquer strategy to first group strings into "roughly similar" subsets, and then calculate each string pair within a subset. For example, say I have the following 5 strings,

```
str1 = "this is a sentence"
str2 = "this is also a sentence"
str3 = "Mary loves elephants"
str4 = "Mary loves an elephant"
str5 = "Mark loves elephants"
```

I hope to have a subset [str1, str2] and another subset [str3, str4, str5]. Then I'll compare str1 and str2 to see if they are similar. I'll also compare str3, str4, str5 to find a similar pair. The total calculations will be reduced from C^2_5=10 to C^2_2+C^2_3=4.

The dividing needs to be fast, and therefore does not need to be accurate. Subsets can be overlapping. And it is acceptable if occasionally a string's similar pair is not included in the same subset, -- then I'll scan a near subset.

I was trying to find an order-preserved hash method to roughly map strings to integers (collision does not matter), and check each string against candidate strings with close integers. But I fail to find such an algorithm.

I'm using Python, and I'll be willing to try if a solution is only applicable in another programming language.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Sounds remarkably similar to a job-interview task that I have once encountered.

Comment: @goodvibration Could you please recall some solution ideas? I'm facing a task to align two scientific publication libraries, each of which contains ~100 million academic paper titles. I'm planning to divide by publish years and compare paper titles, hoping to further reduce the calculations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Levenshtein distance as a key function when sorting.

```
import requests
import Levenshtein as L

def download_moby_dick():
    moby_dick_url = 'https://www.gutenberg.org/files/2701/2701-0.txt'
    return requests.get(moby_dick_url).text

def sentences_in_book(book):
    sentences = (s for s in re.split(r'[.;?!]\s|\r\n\r\n', moby_dick))
    sentences = (re.sub('\s+', ' ', s).strip() for s in sentences)
    sentences = (s for s in sentences if len(s) > 10)
    return list(sentences)

sentences = sentences_in_book(download_moby_dick())

# sort by length
sentences.sort(key=len)

# median length sentence
target = sentences[len(sentences)//2]

# sort by levenshtein distance to target
def keyfunc(sentence):
    return L.distance(target, sentence) 

sentences.sort(key=keyfunc)
```

This will give a rough order where similar sentences are grouped together. To speed it up, you might have to split up the task further. For example abbreviate the input sentences by only using some letters from each word, only search sentences that have roughly the same length, etc.

Comment: If python is not fast enough, you could try using postgresql. It has built in support for levenshtein and trigram search. Combined with indexing, it should be significantly faster than a pure python solution. There are python adaptors and ORMs for working with postgresql with python code.

Comment: Thank you. This is a great idea to divide that maps strings to integers ensuring that similar strings will be close.

Comment: For initial sorting of a very large list of strings, there might be other algorithms that are faster than Levenshtein, possibly at the cost of accuracy. You might want to benchmark the algorithms avalable in this package. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Distance/